# Tomcat running in IntelliJ throws UnmarshalException

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have changed a Java class which is deployed inside a Weblogic Server as a *.war file and also inside a JSP gui inside Tomcat ("external source" deployment). Now this Java class received a new "serialVersionUID", because it is generated code.

Looks like this:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7417232213234280059L;
```

I found the same generated code in the *.war build by maven, so its fine. But when I run my Tomcat and the application uses the same java class, the following error is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: mypackage.MyClass; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7417232213234280059, local class serialVersionUID = -2801645274091928331
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
```

I know this sounds like having two different versions of the same class inside Weblogic and the Tomcat, but how can I tell my Tomcat to use the new class?

These are the steps I already tried:

- Rebuild all
- Invalidate cache and restart (classic)
- Restart IntelliJ (even Windows)
- Deployed the Gui project as WAR and I tried also as "External Source" (which should always use the most recent code)
- "Clear Content" on the Tomcat (whatever this does, I don't know, there is no documentation)
- Rebuild on the specific project and everything else
- Build project automatically option in Settings enabled
- Deleted the C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\tomcat\9256eb14-078c-4ce4-a9fb-835adfd28d66\temp folder, no success

The same project works perfectly with Eclipse, even when I make new changes. Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to use the new code? As I already mentioned "Invalidate cache and restart" did not work in this case.

Stacktrace:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: mypackage.MyClass; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7417232213234280059, local class serialVersionUID = -2801645274091928331
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at weblogic.common.internal.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:120)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:135)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:56)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:164)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: This just means that the session, which was serialized and written to disk, can not be restored. It is pretty normal since one of your classes changed. You just need to log into your application again.

Comment: Hi Piotr, I log into my application every time I restart the Tomcat. It seems that the Tomcat stores the same old class with the old serialVersionUID somewhere and reuses it without recompiling. I even tried to add the option "Build project automatically" which is similar to the "Build automatically" option in Eclipse. No success.

Comment: Can you add the complete stack trace of the error to the question?

Comment: Sure, I added the stacktrace.

Comment: `but how can I tell my Tomcat to use the new class?` - check this class inside the artifact which you deploy to Tomcat server.

Comment: Finally I found the solution: inside WEB-INF there is a "lib" folder with an older version of the library. When I opened it with 7-Zip and decompiled the class, there was the old serialVersionUID.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Gui Application running with Tomcat is a **WEB-INF/lib** folder. There was still an older version of the code inside a library which is loaded by the application. So the problem was a legacy deployment procedure that copies the library to this folder. It was not activated during the build process. Anyway thank you all for your help.